# How to reuse code in multiple Enum

Tags: java, oop, enums

As we know that java enum class :

1. implicitly extends java.lang.Enum;
2. can't extends from any other enum classes.

I have multiple enum class,like below:

```
enum ResourceState {
    RUNNING, STOPPING,STARTTING;//...
    void aMethod() {
        // ...
    }
}

enum ServiceState {
    RUNNING, STOPPING,STARTTING,ERROR;//...
    void aMethod() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

the method `aMethod()` in enum `ResourceState` and `ServiceState` is exactly the same.

in OOP,if `ResourceState` and `ServiceState` are not enum,they should abstract the same method to an super Abstract class,like this:

```
abstract class AbstractState{
    void aMethod() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

but ResourceState is unable to extends from AbstractState,Do you have any idea to work around?

Comment: What you mean 'exactly the same'? Is there no reference of both the enum? If that, you could extract the logic into a static method.

Comment: That's what I'm doing now,but I'm looking for a better solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah yes, this limitation has bitten me a couple of times. Basically, it happens whenever you have anything but the most trivial model on which you apply the enum.

The best way I found to work around this was a utility class with static methods that are called from your `aMethod`.

Comment: Yes,that meight be the best way to minimize the duplicated code

Answer (score 5):

Enums cannot extend other classes, but can implement interfaces. So, a more object oriented approach would be to make your enums implement a common interface and then use delegation to a support class that provides the real implemetation:

```
public interface SomeInterface {
    void aMethod();
}

public class SomeInterfaceSupport implements SomeInterface {
    public void aMethod() {
      //implementation
    }
}

public enum ResourceState implements SomeInterface {
    RUNNING, STOPPING,STARTTING;

    SomeInterfaceSupport someInterfaceSupport;

    ResourceState() {
        someInterfaceSupport = new SomeInterfaceSupport();
    }

    @Override
    public void aMethod() {
        someInterfaceSupport.aMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `public class SomeInterfaceSupport` have to be `public class SomeInterfaceSupport implements SomeInterface` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the enum with the old "Type Safe Enum design pattern":

```
public class ResourceState {
    private ResourceState() {
    }

    public void aMethod() { .... }

    public static ResourceState RUNNING = new ResourceState();
    public static ResourceState STOPPING = new ResourceState();
    ....
}
```

And then extend it and override aMethod if needed.