# How to re-use duplicate code with Enums in Java 8?

Tags: java, generics, enums

I have 3 enumerator classes in my application. All 3 classes have 2 duplicate methods that we want available in every enum that we implement.

```
public static List<String> supported(){
    return Arrays.asList([[EnumClass]].values())
                 .stream().map(Enum::name).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public static boolean contains(String value){

    boolean response = false;

    try {
        response = value != null ? [[EnumClass]].valueOf(value.trim().toUppercase()) != null : false;

    } catch (Exception e){
        LOGGER.error("ERROR: {}", e);
    }
    return response;
}
```

The only part of these methods that changes is the **EnumClass** which is the class of each enum.

The first method will print all the possible values for the enum class and the second method will return true/false if the given String can be made into the enum class.

I tried to implement an Interface that implemented these methods, but I can't use values() because it's not part of the Enum API. I can't relate the methods to each class specifically because the methods are public static. I can't create a custom class and extend Enum to extend that since Java doesn't support multiple inheritance.

For the meanwhile I have my code working, but the duplication really bothers me and I feel like it can be way better. If we continue to add new enumerators then the duplication will just get worse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reuse code in multiple Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523925/how-to-reuse-code-in-multiple-enum)

Comment: You can use [`Class.getEnumConstants()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants--) and [`Enum.valueOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-) to get enum values dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have the Enum class implement an interface, but you can keep a static reference to an object on each enum, and those objects can implement a common interface.  This will reduce the amount of duplication.

```
public static class EUtils<E extends Enum<E>> {

    private final E[] values;
    private Function<String,E> valueOf;

    public EUtils(E[] values, Function<String,E> valueOf) {
        this.values = values;
        this.valueOf = valueOf;
    }

    public List<String> supported(){
        return Arrays.asList(values)
                     .stream().map(Enum::name).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public boolean contains(String value){

        boolean response = false;

        try {
            response = value != null ? valueOf.apply(value.trim().toUpperCase()) != null : false;

        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }
}



private enum Directions {
    LEFT,
    RIGHT;

    public static EUtils<Directions> enumUtils = new EUtils<>(Directions.values(),Directions::valueOf);

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Directions.enumUtils.contains("LEFT"));
    System.out.println(Directions.enumUtils.contains("X"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for.