# How to remove common code in similar Java String based Enums

Tags: java, enums

I have a class that may have several enums within it.
Each enum is supposed to have a string value associated with each entry.
In order to achieve this, I have added a parametrized constructor,a supporting string class member and overridern the toString method.

However one can see that 50% of the code between my two enums are same. It's just the code to support mapping strings to the Enum values.

How can I move this code to a common place and avoid **code duplication**?

Edit: Use case is to easily obtain "New York" when I write America.STATES.NY.

Here's what I tried,
1) I tried using a common interface, but the constructors are different.
2) I tried using inheritance, but enums cannot be inherited

```
public class America {
    public enum STATES {
        NY("New York"), CA("California");
        String displayName;

        STATES(String displayName) {
            this.displayName = displayName;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.displayName;
        }
    }

    public enum PROVINCES {
        ON("Ontario"), QU("Qubec");

        String displayName;

        PROVINCES(String displayName) {
            this.displayName = displayName;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.displayName;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You _could_ use an interface. I don't know how "but the constructors are different" is supposed to be a reason against that.

Comment: Can you please explain the use case? What i can recommend based on the given context, is create an enum with two parameters - public enum LocationData("name", "type"). You can have type as an enum if required.

Comment: By using interfaces, the intended functionality will break. One can't simply access America.STATES.NY with less wrapper core

Comment: @trim24 , Thank you for the clarification. The use case is to be able to simply get "New York" when using America.STATES.NY. I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Make an interface with a default method toString. Implement the interface in the enum, then you can skip writing toString.

Comment: A default interface method cannot override an Object method, you would need something like `asString()` and explicitly call it when constructing strings

Comment: Not to mention you'd need a way to access `displayName` in the parent interface, which would necessitate some form of either type checking, or another method like `#getDisplayName`. Neither of these end up more succinct in implementation on the enum itself. I think the _best_ way is to not store this data within enums but some other storage type intended for data. Barring that, the solution of including a type for states vs provinces would make it shorter to write. It just seems like a minor detail to make major distinctions on in data.

Answer (score 1):

A typical phrase I like to use is "data isn't a part of behavior, and doesn't belong in the code". To be clear (and from my experience), it's much easier to adopt or translate a system that relies on the data for it being loaded from *something* rather than representing the data in hard-coded values.

```
public class Region {
    private final String name;
    public Region(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public String getDisplayName() { return this.name; }
    public String toString() { return getDisplayName(); }
}

public class Country {
    //keeps a map/list of "regions", whether states or provinces or some other type
    public Region getRegion(Object key); //lookup a region based on some key, I'll use strings here
}

Country america = /* a country supplied from somewhere */;
String name = america.getRegion("NY").getDisplayName(); //"New York"
```

This type of approach, while sub-optimal for hard-coded references in your code (like `getRegion("NY")`), is much more forgiving when you need to modify the data later or make a reference which is loaded from elsewheres (e.g. a user-supplied `Region` or lookup name). If you use a database, you can keep your code up-to-date without ever having to change the project, just the database itself. And in the end, since all of this data-related information is stored elsewheres, the overall amount of code to handle is vastly reduced.

You can also later add in something to support determining whether a given administrative region is a state or province or something else (which I think an enum is *great* for):

```
public enum RegionType {
    STATE, PROVINCE, ADMIN_REGION, OTHER,
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an EnumUtils class and add a static instance of it to every enum class.  I implemented an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48199147/7949301.